# How to get a DateTime duration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm baffled how to do this.

I need to take a datetime object and get the duration in hours, days, whatever, to the current time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting the duration in seconds is easy:

```
>> foo = Time.new
=> Mon Dec 29 18:23:51 +0100 2008
>> bar = Time.new
=> Mon Dec 29 18:23:56 +0100 2008
>> print bar - foo
5.104063=> nil
```

So, a little over five seconds.

But to present this in a somewhat more human-friendly form, you'll need a third-party addition, like [`time_period_to_s`](http://www.postal-code.com/binarycode/2007/04/04/english-friendly-timespan/), or the `Duration` package.

Answer (score 4):

[`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001475) will give you a string representation of the time  between two time/date objects.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) class rather than DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using rails, then [distance_of_time_in_words_to_now](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001477) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i just want to share my code in order to get more readable duration time.

instead of using [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001475) like @Ryan Bigg suggest, i like @Sören Kuklau suggestion more.

but to show human-friendly form, i make something like this.

```
def get_duration opts
    from = Time.parse opts[:from]
    to   = Time.parse opts[:to]

    duration      = to - from
    durationLabel = []
    separator     = " "

    hours = (duration / 3600).floor
    restDuration = duration%3600

    durationLabel << "#{hours}h" if hours > 0

    return durationLabel.join separator if restDuration.floor == 0

    minutes = (restDuration / 60).floor
    restDuration = duration%60

    durationLabel << "#{minutes}m" if minutes > 0

    return durationLabel.join separator if restDuration.floor == 0

    seconds = restDuration.floor

    durationLabel << "#{seconds}s" if seconds > 0

    durationLabel.join separator
end

get_duration from: "2018-03-15 11:50:43", to: "2018-03-15 11:51:50"
# return 1m 7s
```

it will calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds.
instead of getting a vague response like **`about 1 minutes`** or hard response like **`67.0`**, we will get something more human-friendly but accurate until second like **`1m 7s`**